# How and where to put the params path to calling URL

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I’ve an application ( **cass** ) who need to call the same URL(**mobd-api.corp**) with different path .

```
ds-ap-service https://mobd-api.corp/ap
ds-ids-service https://mobd-api.corp/ids
ds-chat-service https://mobd-api.corp/chat
```

My problem is i dont **know how and where** to **set** the **different path**. Do i’ve to do it in pod.yaml or do i’ve to create an ingress ?

Do you think it’s a good idea to create a PV, PVC for all the configs files that i’ve ? around 10 files

Comment: ingress is the way to go here. You can map different URIs to different services. As for config files, you can create a ConfigMap and map them to different volumes.

Comment: thank yor your reply . do you have an example for ConfigMap and map them to different volumes ?

Comment: Have a look at a helm example of how configs from configMaps are being mounted. This will give you a general best practise. You can then reverse engineer from there. https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-deployment.yaml#L77

Comment: Could you please summarize your solution and post it as an answer for this question ? This will help others find the solution much easier.